# Input fields get local values even after clearing

Tags: jsf-2

I have a few input fields in a form which are submitted using Save button and there is a Clear button to clear the input fields using a clear method which clears the values using setSubmittedValue("");

There is a selectonemenu on the top with a valueChangeListener which calls a method in backing bean to add a set of extra input fields for certain value of selectonemenu.(This field has ajax)

First I enter some values(invalid) on the input fields and click Save so that the validation fails and displays error messages.
Then I click Clear to clear the input fields and they clear.

Now if I click on selectonemenu to change its value, the input fields display the invalid values that I entered.

Is there any way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the submitted value with an empty string instead of `null`. This way it will be displayed during render instead of the local value. However, on the subsequent request it becomes `null` again and the local value will be displayed instead.

The clear button should have called [`EditableValueHolder#resetValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html#resetValue%28%29) instead of `EditableValueHolder#setSubmittedValue()`.

Comment: It works when I clear the bean values as well as local values when I change the selectonemenu, Thanks for the answer...