# JSF2 Component retains the old invalid value

Tags: jsf-2

We have with four/five fields (one field is select box - ajax) , attached with validators(custom validators). We have a clear button in the form.
    When we select the value from selectbox and the form is submitted , in case of any validation errors ,we show validation errors .When we press clear ,we render the div with ajax call and all fields are clear and validations errors also cleared.
    But....if we select the value from select box ,which was first selected then it retains the old invalid enteries in the form fields.

Any clues , why it retained the old values , is there any way to clear it ?

Comment: Is this your colleague? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425447/input-fields-get-local-values-even-after-clearing

Answer (score 0):

Without posting your XML though, it's difficult to tell what's happening. I've had a similar issue: Because the values were not cleared from the backing bean, just the page, you check the box, it pushes the values back to the page.

You could clear the values from the backing bean, or just set only part of the form to render on your f:ajax rather than the entire form.

Comment: I render the entire DIV ,in the listener if i just clear the backing bean , it doesn't clear the values , we need to UIComponent.resetValue()....is that the only way..